# Android source build error: ld cannot find -lhistory

Tags: android, linker-errors

**SOLVED**  readline - a library for editing typed command lines

---

After following the Android open source directions [here](http://source.android.com/source/download.html), for the life of me I cannot figure out what is missing. I am building on Fedora 14 x86_64.

```
host Executable: sqlite3 (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/sqlite3_intermediates/sqlite3)
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhistory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/sqlite3_intermediates/sqlite3] Error 1
```

So does anyone know what this could come from? I installed every sqlite library I could think of. Which ever library this is my searches have turned up nothing. Anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed libreadline5 - I think the libhistory.so comes with that package. If you have then see if you have a symlink /lib/libhistory.so which points to /lib/libhistory.so.x.